# Fetching values from a list in Python

Tags: python, list

```
values = ['random word1', 20, 'random word2', 54]

values = list(map(list,zip(values[::2], values[1::2])))

print(values)

[['random word1', 20], ['random word2', 54]]
```

Now I want to fetch values
like this:

`if ‘random word2’ in values:`

get the value associated with random word 2 which is in this case 54.

Note: string words and values are random.

How can I do that?

I need to fetch the correct value.

Comment: Why not save the data in a `dict` instead of a list of tuples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a dictionary over a list is the way to go

```
d = dict(zip(values[::2], values[1::2]))
print(d['random word1'])  # -> 20
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    value = values[values.index("random words2") + 1]
except ValueError:
    value = None
```

Or, if you need to fecth more values, convert your list to a dictionary and then use the `get` method. Even for 2 retrievals this will already be more efficient, algorithmically wise:

```
# make N 2-tuples treating the odd-positioned elements as keys and 
# even ones as values, and call the dict constructor with that:
v = dict([i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(values), 2))
v.get("random word2")
```

Comment: I tried your first method, when the list is like this: `['random word1', 20, 'random word2', 54]` it works but when the list is like this: `[['random word1', 20], ['random word2', 54]]` it doesn’t work. It says "random word2" is not in list. What is the fix?

Comment: Also I am using this to fetch only 1 value thats why I would like to use the first method you have provided.